# How to extract a parameter from a URL using a regex pattern

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, nokogiri

I’m having trouble with a matching expression.  I want to extract the "code" parameter from  a link I extracted using Nokogiri,  so I tried:

```
event_id = a.attr("href").match(/\?code=(\d+)/)[1]
```

Unfortunately what is extracted is the entire query string:

```
?code=768140119
```

What is the proper way to just get the value of the parameter and nothing else?

Comment: And if you use `a.attr("href")[/\?code=(\d+)/, 1]`? Or just `a.attr("href")[/\d+/]` (if there is only 1 sequence of one or more digits)?

Comment: Also, try `a["href"][/\d+/]`

Comment: Can you show the input and the output? Are you really accessing `[1]` of the match?

Comment: It does work? http://rubular.com/r/ED3hgfEzuF. I also tried it on ruby 2.3.1.

Comment: THe only reason "[/\d+/]" doesn't work is there may be multiple sequences of numbers.  The only one I care about is the one following "code=".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use regular expressions, use a well-tested wheel.

Ruby's [URI](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html) class is your friend, in particular [`decode_www_form`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html#method-c-decode_www_form):

```
require 'uri'

uri = URI.parse('http://foo.com?code=768140119')
uri.query # => "code=768140119"
URI.decode_www_form(uri.query) # => [["code", "768140119"]]
URI.decode_www_form(uri.query).to_h # => {"code"=>"768140119"}
```

As for extracting the value of a parameter of a tag, Nokogiri makes it easy, just treat the Node like a hash:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML("
<html>
  <body>
    <a href='path/to/foo'>bar</a>
  </body>
</html>
")

doc.at('a')['href'] # => "path/to/foo"
```

You don't need to waste time typing `attr(...)`.

Comment: THe URL is a relative one (e.g. "../results?code=abcde").  Will this still work with a relative URL?

Comment: What did you try? "[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/128421)" is important.